# save ipython html object as pdf

Tags: python, html, pdf, matplotlib, ipython

I'm plotting some data using `shap`, which returns me (in console) a 
`<IPython.core.display.HTML object>`. I would like to convert the object to a PDF and save it.

I do understand that there is some hassle, as I probably would need to simulate a browser to open and view the HTML in.

What would be the most straight-forward way of storing the html output as PDF?

Please note that I am not inside a browser/iPython notebook, and I do not want to create and convert a whole iPython notebook.

Comment: Here is what I would try (this is totally untested though): The html object might have a `__repr__` which returns the actual html. Converting html to pdf [should be possible](http://www.google.de/search?q=python+htmltopdf).